# Access to hash.web denied

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

When I am attempting to debug an ASP.NET web form, I am getting the following error:

> Error  6   Access to the path 'C:\Users\Abhishek Panday\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\wscecommerce\767781f0\ea1824bb\hash\hash.web' is denied.

We have attempted to delete the temporary ASP.NET files folder but that doesn't work. I would really appreciate it if you could provide some suggestions to solve this problem.

Comment: I believe that the messages says it all. You do not have set the correct permissions !

Answer (score -2):

you can try delete, 
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files

Good luck

Comment: Why to do that ? The problem is not on that directory. Also if you try to delete this shared temporary directory first you destroy the permission that have, and you do not know what to place again, and second you delete the temporary files of all sites that use it. And I am not sure if the asp.net create it automatically again. Also you probably fail to delete it if the VS and the IIS is running. Bad idea in general.